# IOS stopUpdatingLocation doesn't stops gps on certain phone

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager, ios6

Hey I got really strange issue for last few days.

I am writing an social app and I'v been testing it on two phones (both IPhone 5) white and black.
Black phone is my boss's phone and it has installed IOS 6.0.1, white phone has IOS 6.0.

The problem is that on the black phone stopUpdatingLocation doesn't stops the gps.
I'v created empty app with gps only and we have same bug .. but when I change bundle ID everything works ok.

Second important thing is that when we restored the white phone from black phone's back up and cleared the black one the bug occurs on the white phone and doesn't occurs on the black one. So it seems it's related to phone settings.

Anyway.
We can't change bundle ID cause app is already on app store (I am writing new refreshed version of it).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Gps is not stopped when there is another app or apple using it. You can see that in the settings menu which applicatio uses gps on the lila arrow icon.